# search and replace a space with a tab at a specific location in a string

Tags: python

I need some help replacing a space with a tab on a string with multiple spaces.
I need to search the string for a time format such as 08:20:10 and replace the space on the end with a tab.
My code is the following:

```
alert = '9/14/2016 08:20:10 CH1 This is a test.'
str = re.sub (r'(/d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\s)$', '\t', alert)
```

I've been unsuccessful in this endeavor. The output should look like:

```
9/14/2016 08:20:10    CH1 This is a test.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a *positive lookbehind* without a line terminator:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s', '\t', alert)
'9/14/2016 08:20:10\tCH1 This is a test.'
>>>
>>> print(_)
9/14/2016 08:20:10      CH1 This is a test.
```

Also, your `/d` should have read `\d`

Comment: Yea, I fat fingered the /d for the first digit. Thanks this worked.

Comment: @mcristan No problems. I figured it must have been a typo

Answer (score 2):

Couple things to fix in your expression:

- `/d` should have been `\d`
- no need for the end of the string match `$`

Also, I would use a [positive look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of a capturing group:

```
(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s
```

Works for me:

```
>>> print(re.sub(r'(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s', '\t', alert))
9/14/2016 08:20:10  CH1 This is a test.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't name your variable `str`, as this masks the built-in function of that name.

Second, I don't see the need for regex here. Simply `split` the string and then rejoin it however you like.

```
>>> alert = '9/14/2016 08:20:10 CH1 This is a test.'
>>> l = alert.split()
>>> new_alert = ' '.join(l[:2]) + '\t' + ' '.join(l[2:])
>>> new_alert
'9/14/2016 08:20:10\tCH1 This is a test.'
```

You can also repair your original expression by referring to the captured group in the replacement substring (and fixing the `/` to a `\`):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub (r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\s)', r'\1\t', alert)
'9/14/2016 08:20:10\tCH1 This is a test.'
```

Comment: That's extremely problem specific; it _works_ if the format is _exactly_ what was given, but it's solving a very different problem that just happens to overlap the specified problem, in a way that obscures the real goal from future maintainers. The regex says "change space after timestamp to tab"; this code says "change third run of whitespace to a tab (oh, and change all runs of whitespace to single spaces while removing leading and trailing whitespace; hope that's not a problem)". I'm not a fan of regex overuse, but I'd consider this a cure worse than the disease.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - As far as maintainability, I took one look at the regex and immediately decided that I didn't want to maintain it and would rather use a solution without regex. :P However, I took some more looks at the regex and came to the conclusion that it wasn't so bad, so I fixed it in my edit.